# Assigning a dynamic array using declaration for static array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

So for example,

```
int aaa(unsigned int par1, unsigned int par2){
  int array[par1*par2];
  return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling the code that contains this, and it compiled well and had no run-time issue - the array was properly created.

But I know that this is basically declaring a dynamic array in static array declaration fashion. What may go wrong with this declaration? Will there be a compiler issue in a different compiler?

Comment: There will be a compiler issue if the chain you're using doesn't support VLA's. Fwiw, a C11 implementation can legally claim it does **not** support the feature by defining `__STDC_NO_VLA__`. The usefulness of that is arguable (at least to me), as a failure to compile would be a certain indicator regardless.

Answer (score 5):

This is correct as per the 1999 C standard.  The 2011 standard changed it to be an *optional* feature, which in practice means that all C11 compilers will support it except for MSVC.

Before 1999 some compilers offered this as a non-standard extension.

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+variable-length-array) to StackOverflow search for other questions on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

> But I know that this is basically declaring a dynamic array in static array declaration fashion.

This is called VLA *(Variable-Length Array)*. This array is *not* static - it is placed in automatic memory (also known as "the stack").

> What may go wrong with this declaration?

It may overflow the stack when the size of the array exceeds a certain limit specific to your system.

> Will there be a compiler issue in a different compiler?

This is a C99 feature, so compiler that do not support C99 may fail to compile this code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a C99-only feature. It's called [VLA (variable-length arrays)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

The C++0x does't support VLA:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c++/K_4lgA1JYeg

But some compilers might not be strictly compliant with the standard.

Comment: C++0x is ancient history now; you could talk about C++11 or C++14 which have been released (without VLAs), or C++1z which is scheduled for 2017.  However this is a C question.